# How to Merge also map the group of JSON object array by key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do you group an array of objects by an object key to create a new array list of objects based on the grouping? For example, I have an array of objects:

```
 {
       "List": [
          {
             "column1": "Name",
              "column2" :"Gender",
              "column3" :"Phone",
              "column4" :'Age',
             "items": [
                {
                   "column1": "SR",
                   "column2" :"M",
                   "column3" :"1223322",
                    "column4" :'23',
                },
                {
                   "column1": "SA",
                   "column2" :"F",
                   "column3" :"1322222",
                    "column4" :'26',
                },
             ]
          }
```

and my expected output :

```
List :[
{
               "Name": "SR",
              "Gender" :"M",
              "Phone" :"1223322",
              "Age" :'23',
    {...}
    ]
```

I dont know how to map this ? Please help me to resolve. Thanks

Comment: Why is `"List"` an array? are there going to be multiple entries in that array, each with their own "items" array inside?

Comment: And adding more to @AndrewParks's question, would the objects in the array "List" always have the same keys, "column1", "column2" etc ..?

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic property access to convert the column names in the original items based on the mappings in the containing object.

Use `.flatMap()` to flatten the array of objects with nested `items` arrays into a single array of items.

```js
const data = {
  "List": [{
    "column1": "Name",
    "column2": "Gender",
    "column3": "Phone",
    "column4": 'Age',
    "items": [{
        "column1": "SR",
        "column2": "M",
        "column3": "1223322",
        "column4": '23',
      },
      {
        "column1": "SA",
        "column2": "F",
        "column3": "1322222",
        "column4": '26',
      },
    ]
  }]
};

data.List = data.List.flatMap(d =>
  d.items.map(item =>
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => [d[key], value]))));

console.log(data);
```